# .HTA file source code displayed

Tags: hta

I have written the script in a .hta  file and saved it on an apache server.
Then I hit the appropriate url stating the hta file.
In IE8 the file is executed and prompts for open, save, saveas.
But in Mozilla and chrome the content of the hta file is displayed in the browser

Comment: **hta** files are IE only

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the mime type for HTA correctly in Apache (it ought to be `application/hta`)?

IE 8 is probably compensating, but, Chrome and Firefox probably have no idea what it is. With the correct mime type being set in Apache, then, Chrome and Firefox will more likely react in the way you expect it to.